How to style background color and text color for a ToolbarItem on a Maui Blazor Hybrid App TabbedPage?
I am trying to change the background color and text color of a ToolBarItem on Maui Blazor Hybrid app TabbedPage. I am not using Shell and this project didn't create a default Styles.xaml in Resources folder.
Also to note, I am using NavigationPage when I am calling the MainPage.
I tried to style it in App.xaml file but it doesn't reflect that change on any of the devices, windows, ios or android. I also tried to style using CssClass, and setting color there, but that didn't work either.
Code from App.xaml.cs :
var navigationPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage(nameof(Weather)));
MainPage = navigationPage;

Code snippet from MainPage for TabbedPage :
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <Label Text="Sample Title Goes Here!" StyleClass="NavigationTitle"/>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
<TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>        
    <ToolbarItem Text="ToolbarItem Order1" Priority="1" Order="Primary" />
    <ToolbarItem Text="{Binding LoginText}" Priority="4" Order="Secondary" Command="{Binding LoginCommand} />
<TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>

Code snippet from App.xaml for styling :
<Style TargetType="ToolbarItem">
    <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="pink"/>
</Style>

NOTE: There is no color properties on ToolbarItem, hence using Shell.BackgroundColor, just to show what I tried. I also tried to set target type as TabbedPage and NavigationPage, none of which worked.
App Screenshot (Windows) :
The dropdown in the screenshot should show text "Login", currently it is white and I cant change the color.
App Screenshot

The issue is related with .NET Maui Secondary ToolbarItem Issue on Windows #18258.
As an alternative workaround, you can change the color of text "Login" by setting BarTextColor in App.xaml on Windows platform:
<Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
         <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="Pink" />
         <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="Red" />
</Style>



Thanks for the link Alexandar, yes it's exactly the same issue. I have tried your workaround but that does nothing either.

@Krishie Thanks for your update, you may set TargetType as TargetType="TabbedPage", see the working screenshot.

@Alexander thanks. Not quite sure how you got it working, but the same code doesn't work for me. Please see the snippet of code from App.xaml. Do you see anything odd?
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>            
        <StyleSheet Source="/Resources/Styles/AppStyles.css" />

        <Style TargetType="TabbedPage">
            <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="Pink" />
            <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>


@Krishie Thanks for your update, after checking, your snippet of code from App.xaml looks fine.  Looks like your MainPage is a  TabbedPage, since you use  new NavigationPage(new MainPage(nameof(Weather))), you still need to set TargetType="NavigationPage". If you still can't get it working, you can follow the issue: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18258. :)

@Alexander, thanks much. Yeah it does work finally with your help!

@Krishie Thanks for the response, have a great day! :)
